Homotopy invariance axiom, singular homology.
I am trying to prove the homotopy axiom defining the chain homotopy:
$$P_n:S_n(X)\rightarrow S_{n+1}(X), \quad P_n(\sigma)=F\circ(\sigma\times Id)\circ c,$$ where

$F:X\times I\rightarrow Y$ is the homotopy between continuous applications $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$
$c:\Delta ^{n+1}\rightarrow \Delta ^n\times I, (t_0,...,t_{n+1})\mapsto (\frac{t_0}{1-t_{n+1}},...,\frac{t_n}{1-t_{n+1}},t_{n+1})$ if $t_{n+1}<1$ and $c(0,...,0,1) = (0,...,0,1)$ if $t_{n+1}=1$ (since the vector $(t_i)_i$ is in $\Delta^{n+1}$, $t_{n+1}=1\implies t_i=0,\, i\neq n+1$). (We take barycentric coordinates $(t_0,...,t_{n+1})\in \Delta ^{n+1}$).

It is easy prove that $P$ is well defined, but I can't get the term $g(\sigma)$ to prove the identity $\partial P +P \partial =f-g$ (or something similar depending on how the signs alter the result) or I don't understand if it suffices to prove that $P(\sigma)$ evaluated at $(0,\dotsc,0,1)$ gives $g(\sigma (0))$ actually.

Shouldn't $c$ be a map of form $\Delta^{n+1}\to\Delta^n\times I$? In which case, your definition  at $t_{n+1}=1$ is suspect. How this usually goes is you take a sum of similar $c$ and overall get a triangulation, using multiple $(n+1)$-simplices, of $\Delta^n\times I$; one then uses this chain to get the homotopy. Are you taking this $c$ from a book, or was this your own proof-attempt?

@FShrike you are right, but it is not suspect since the numerators goes to zero faster than the denominators then $t_{n+1}$ goues to 1, so it is continuous in all $\Delta^{n+1}$. It is my own proof-attempt to avoid using the division into simplices of $\Delta^n\times I$ as in Allen Hatcher's book.

No I’m sure it’s continuous as a map to $\Bbb R^{n+1}\times I$, but it would map to $((0,0,\cdots,0),1)$ which does not represent an element of $\Delta^n\times I$. I am not convinced a single such $c$ will work anyway, the subdivision into multiple subsimplices is natural and it works; Hatcher’s proof is quite classical

Oh you are right, I think it couldn't be proved with the aplication c.

@FShrike In any case, how does Hatcher evaluate the points in each summand? If he does it using barycentric coordinates in the order in which the vertices appear, then he could map the point $(0,…,0,1)$ to $(\sigma(0),1)$, but $\sigma$ is not defined at 0, as you have pointed out.

I'm not fully sure what you mean. I recommend you ask a new question which focuses on any specific doubts you have with "Hatcher's" proof
